# Errors in Linux Mint update manager

Tags: linux-mint, apt, package-management

Linux Mint's (I'm using Linux Mint Mate edition, 17.2 32 bit) update manager gives me:

[image]

I tried this from the terminal:

```
sudo rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists
sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/apt/lists/partial
sudo aptitude update
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

While that does make the problem go away, the issue is not solved because the same thing happens again.

So, how can I fix this problem?

Comment: I removed the `&` between your commands, you didn't actually run the commands with the `&`, did you? Did the commands return any error messages? What do you mean you "sometimes" get the error? Does `sudo apt-get update` solve the problem but it happens again later? What version of Linux Mint are you using? Please [edit] your question to provide these details. Oh, and yes, this is the right site for the question but please don't use flags for such clarifications.

Comment: " Does sudo apt-get update solve the problem but it happens again later"-yes. "What version of Linux Mint are you using?"-i was write-17.2-so, where can i to contact with moderator to clarifications? i know that if the topic write witg error it's may to closed.how you organize right the Commands in this Post?

Comment: Oh, sorry, you're right. It was in the title, I didn't notice it. You can format your posts using the [formatting tools](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting). As for contacting a moderator, you can do so by clicking on the "flag" link under your question. Don't do that unless there is a serious problem however. That said, I'm a moderator, what can I help you with?